# Transactions with PDO and prep. statements

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I need to insert to two tables and I tried transactions. It works well:

```
$nom = "Nrc";
$contrasenya = "somePassword"; 

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $conn->exec("INSERT INTO usuari (nom, contrasenya) 
                 VALUES ('$nom', '$contrasenya')");
    $conn->exec("INSERT INTO well (puntuacio, text) 
                 VALUES ('9', 'some text2')");

    $conn->commit();
    echo "New records created successfully";
```

Now I want to introduce prep. statements for security. I am not sure how to do that. This is what I tried. It gives me no error, but it does not insert in any table either:

```
$nom = "Nrc";
$contrasenya = "somePassword"; 

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuari (nom, contrasenya) 
                            VALUES (:nom, :contrasenya)");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO well (puntuacio, text) 
                            VALUES ('9', 'some text2')");

    $stmt->bindParam(':nom', $nom);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contrasenya', $contrasenya);
    $conn->commit();
    echo "New records created successfully";
```

Comment: You never execute the statement

Comment: Passwords should be hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You never [`execute`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the statement.
2. You overwrite your statement (`$stmt`) with the statement using the values directly. So you don't use the correct prepared statement.

You can use the following code to `INSERT` the values to the tables:

```
//start the transaction.
$conn->beginTransaction();

//the variables of the first statement.
$nom = 'Nrc';
$contrasenya = 'somePassword';

//prepare the first statement, bind the values and execute.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuari (nom, contrasenya) VALUES (:nom, :contrasenya)");
$stmt->bindParam(':nom', $nom);
$stmt->bindParam(':contrasenya', $contrasenya); //TODO - use hashing here!

//... or solution without variable.
//$stmt->bindValue(':nom', 'Nrc');
//$stmt->bindValue(':contrasenya', 'somePassword');

$stmt->execute();

//the variables of the second statement.
$puntuacio = '9';
$text = 'some text2';

//prepare the second statement, bind the values and execute.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO well (puntuacio, text) VALUES (:puntuacio, :text)");
$stmt->bindParam(':puntuacio', $puntuacio);
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $text);

//... or solution without variable.
//$stmt->bindValue(':puntuacio', '9');
//$stmt->bindValue(':text', 'some text2');

$stmt->execute();

//commit all changes of the transaction.
$conn->commit();
```

**Note:** As already others mentioned, you should also [hash your passwords](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php).

Comment: Your code makes sense. But I copy-paste and it does not work. It gives an error on the line $stmt->bindParam(':nom', 'Nrc');

Comment: the error says: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in... that line

Comment: I discovered that it works with a variable: $stmt->bindParam(':nom', $nom); but not with: $stmt->bindParam(':nom', 'Nrc'); (the same with all the bindParam lines)

Comment: @Nrc - updated my answer and fixed the code. `bindParam` only accept variables since it is bind by reference. You can use `bindValue` to directly bind the value.

Comment: Now it is ok. Thank you. Any guess why I have negative points? Before asking I made a search and I could not find nothing similar

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it is a simple typo issue (missing `execute`). As you can see on my answer there were several issues with your code. Don't forget to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Does it mean that I should not ask this question? (or this type of questions) I do not understand, I think I would not be able to solve it alone. I'm not sure how to use this forum

Comment: I recommend to read [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to understand how to use StackOverflow. In my opinion the question is OK.

Answer (score -1):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

Answer (score -1):

For password insertion you should use [password() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)  shiped with PHP.

You shouldn't insert direct data directly in prepare statement, as you did for the first one

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO well (puntuacio, text) 
                        VALUES (:number, :some_text)");
$stmt->bindParam(':number', $num);
$stmt->bindParam(':some_text', $text);
```

You should `execute();` your prepared statement in order to execute your query insertion.

Plus as said previously you overwrite your $stmt variable before you can execute your query.

Comment: Not my vote but could be that this has already been said. The function is `password_hash` not `password`. This code isn't using that function.

Comment: I was typing when answer have been said. 
I know that's the function is pass_hash but you have plemty of password function and it was for research purpose. 
But well okay, thanx for notice it.